# XML parsing Error Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

I made an XML with php and MYSQL, but when i try to parse it into iphone dont seems to work, since in the internet adress it look correctly...Here the XML:

```
<feed xmlns="http://74.53.32.202/~ltashiro/public/Servidor/">
<title>ServidorBaladasRSS</title>
<subtitle>Agenda</subtitle>
<Prog Id="1" Nome="Club" Desc="" Data="2011-11-01 00:00:00" Dia="2"/>
<Prog Id="1" Nome="Club" Desc="" Data="2011-11-01 00:00:00" Dia="3"/>
<Prog Id="1" Nome="Club" Desc="" Data="2011-11-01 00:00:00" Dia="4"/>
<Prog Id="2" Nome="Test" Desc="" Data="2011-11-01 00:00:00" Dia="1"/>
<Prog Id="2" Nome="Test" Desc="" Data="2011-11-01 00:00:00" Dia="2"/>
<Prog Id="2" Nome="Test" Desc="" Data="2011-11-01 00:00:00" Dia="3"/>
<Prog Id="2" Nome="Test" Desc="" Data="2011-11-01 00:00:00" Dia="4"/>
</feed>
```

The Objective-C:

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) nameSpaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict
{
      NSLog(@"%@",elementName);
}
```

I need the XML to be in that format,when i Log the elementName it logs only the feed,title and subtitle, the rest of the XML looks like dont exists...

something wrong with the XML formatting?

Comment: To eliminate a couple of variables, try running your code with text instead of attributes for Prog. Also, run it with the tag name "prog", i.e. lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just put this code into viewDidLoad of a ViewController and ran it and it produced output including your Prog elements (output shown below the code) so double check your data/encoding etc.:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *testXml = @"<feed xmlns=\"http://74.53.32.202/~ltashiro/public/Servidor/\">\
    <title>ServidorBaladasRSS</title>\
    <subtitle>Agenda</subtitle>\
    <Prog Id=\"1\" Nome=\"Club\" Desc=\"\" Data=\"2011-11-01 00:00:00\" Dia=\"2\"/>\
    <Prog Id=\"1\" Nome=\"Club\" Desc=\"\" Data=\"2011-11-01 00:00:00\" Dia=\"3\"/>\
    <Prog Id=\"1\" Nome=\"Club\" Desc=\"\" Data=\"2011-11-01 00:00:00\" Dia=\"4\"/>\
    <Prog Id=\"2\" Nome=\"Test\" Desc=\"\" Data=\"2011-11-01 00:00:00\" Dia=\"1\"/>\
    <Prog Id=\"2\" Nome=\"Test\" Desc=\"\" Data=\"2011-11-01 00:00:00\" Dia=\"2\"/>\
    <Prog Id=\"2\" Nome=\"Test\" Desc=\"\" Data=\"2011-11-01 00:00:00\" Dia=\"3\"/>\
    <Prog Id=\"2\" Nome=\"Test\" Desc=\"\" Data=\"2011-11-01 00:00:00\" Dia=\"4\"/>\
    </feed>";

    NSData *ourData =   [testXml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:ourData];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) nameSpaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict
{
      NSLog(@"%@",elementName);
}
```

This produced the following output:

```
[Session started at 2011-11-02 15:54:01 +1100.]
2011-11-02 15:54:04.965 TESTXML[1517:207] feed
2011-11-02 15:54:04.966 TESTXML[1517:207] title
2011-11-02 15:54:04.967 TESTXML[1517:207] subtitle
2011-11-02 15:54:04.967 TESTXML[1517:207] Prog
2011-11-02 15:54:04.968 TESTXML[1517:207] Prog
2011-11-02 15:54:04.968 TESTXML[1517:207] Prog
2011-11-02 15:54:04.969 TESTXML[1517:207] Prog
2011-11-02 15:54:04.969 TESTXML[1517:207] Prog
2011-11-02 15:54:04.970 TESTXML[1517:207] Prog
2011-11-02 15:54:04.970 TESTXML[1517:207] Prog
```

Comment: After read and read again the code i think there was a problem with the synthax on the objective-C